# Logic Apps Azure Data lake Upload file Action-large files are failing to upload with 413 status code

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-lake

I am trying to upload a file to Azure Data lake using Azure Data lake Upload File action of Logic Apps. It is working fine for small files about 20 MB. But files with 28 MB or greater are failing with Status code 413- request entity too large.

I have enabled Chunking also in the Upload File Action.Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the response George.

I have got a workaround. My scenario involves getting file from SharePoint online and uploading to Azure Data Lake. In earlier setup which had the above issue, I was using SharePoint trigger -When a file is created or modified in a folder, which returns file content, to get the file from SharePoint and Datalake Upload File action to upload it to Azure Data Lake. This setup was failing for files larger than 27MB (request entity too large-413) in File Upload Action even when chunking was enabled at File Upload action.

After some troubleshooting, I got a workaround which involves using another SharePoint trigger-When a file is created or modified in a folder(properties-only). It returns metadeta instead of file content. After getting metadeta I used Get File Content SharePoint Action to get the file content to upload to Azure Data lake which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Logic app has the limits for message, for the Logic Apps message size limit, see [Logic Apps limits and configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config).

However actions that support chunking can access the message content in these outputs. So you just need to set the `Allow chunking` on.

[image]

[image]

I test with a 40MB blob file and it succeeds. Further more information you could refer to this doc:[Handle large messages with chunking in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages). Hope this could help you.